# Google Font Roboto + Bootstrap, are they incompatible?

Tags: html

here my code of head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="description" id="description" content="Unisciti alla nostra Community! Condividi le tue idee e trova qualsiasi cosa su One Piece ed altri Anime/Manga!">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="One Piece Power" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Su One Piece Power potrai trovare qualsiasi cosa riguardande il mondo di One Piece: Episodi, Capitoli, Immagini, Video, Censure, Videogiochi, Guide e tanto altro! Che aspetti! Vieni a visitarci!" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="/images/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow">
  <title>One Piece Power</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" async>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" async>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" async>
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="onepiecepower.info" async>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/spoiler.js"></script>
```

And my style.css

```
body {
    background-image: url("../../images/sfondo.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #d6c3b1;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

If i add this code without the import of bootstrap, it works well but since I entered the bootstrap import it doesn't work anymore.

My site doesn't recognize the font roboto in the site. Why? Thanks

Comment: It's to do with specificity. Import your style.css **after** importing bootstrap

Comment: probably this css is overwritten by the bootsrtrap stylesheet. you can check in your browser dev tools for that

Comment: yeah, it works but now it doesn't recognize text-weight: bold; in the style.css. Can anyone help me again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

> My site doesn't recognize the font roboto in the site. Why? Thanks

From the [CSS spec:](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order)

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.

Order matters, because, when rules conflict, order is a factor in deciding which one wins. In this case, whichever style is declared last, gets the preference

Comment: Thanks, it works but now it doesn't recognize font-weight: bold; in the style.css. Can anyone help me again?

Comment: Because `text-weight` is an invalid property. Try `font-weight` Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp

Comment: sorry, i mean font-weight, i have edited it. Any solutions?

Comment: Maybe open a new question for that. This question does not have enough code to replicate the `font-weight` issue

Answer (score 0):

It's best to list all stylesheets under the bootstrap stylesheet. Code is read from top down left to right. Your bootstrap stylesheet is likely overriding your other stylesheets.